# Eclipse SVN check-in cannot add/edit comment

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I'm trying to check in a new project to SVN and I'm not able to edit the comment field to add whatever text I need to add, I have the same behaviour on other existing files that I edit and commit.  The comment text box is not editable at all, and I cannot use a previously entered comment or template either.

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0), Build id: 20211202-1639.

Is there something in the config files that controls the ability to type text into the SVN comment text box?

Here's a screenshot:

[Screen shot of the commit pop-up, the text box is not editable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xBkI.png)

[Here are the SVN modules I'm using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTdZ0.png)

I'm using Subversive 4.0.5

Comment: You need to show a screenshot and specify the SVN plug-in used in Eclipse. It can be Subversive or Subclipse. Try another plug-in if the current one does not work properly.

Comment: I removed Subversive and installed Subclipse, same issue, nothing has changed.  Seems to not be the plug-in, but Eclipse...

Comment: Now this looks more like a support request to the Eclipse community. Could be a bug in Eclipse since the text box is inactive in both plug-ins.

Comment: bahrep, I'm not sure how to request that.

Answer (score 2):

Resizing the dialog fixes it for me. See: https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/issues/185

I think it is an Eclipse SWT bug in newer versions.

Comment: Thank you Mark Phippard, this one has been stumping me for months! Your resizing the dialog workaround allows me to add/edit an SVN commit comment.

Comment: I can confirm the 22 version still has the same issue